# regex match everything between tags with text

Tags: regex

I have this code

```
<p>
    ##QA##
</p>
<h3>
    qqq
</h3>
<p>
    qqq
</p>
<p>
    ##QA##
</p>
```

There are newlines and indentations. This `<p>\s*##QA##\s*<\/p>` works for matichg `<p>##QA##</p>` 
I would like to match content between both `<p>##QA##</p>`. 
I tried this but it does not work

```
<p>\s*##QA##\s*<\/p>(.*?)<p>\s*##QA##\s*<\/p>
```

Comment: `.` does not match line breaks by default, use `(?s)` inline modifier at the pattern start, or a `[\w\W]` workaround instead of `.`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew [\w\W] worked perfectly thank you

Comment: `.*?` notatshuns shuold be manetained if enjin suppert _Dot-All_ flag. Use `[\S\s]` or `[\D\d]` or `[\W\w]`  or simlex onlery if necessary.